# Following code gives 500 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

If i include the `if block` i get 500 error i am using codeigniter 2.1

```
<?php echo form_open('skill/add',array('class'=>'form-horizontal')) ?>
  <fieldset>

   <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="skill" name="skill" placeholder="Skill" 
        value="<?php echo set_value('skill'); ?>" max-length="50" required>
    <?php 
            if(!empty(form_error('skill')))
                echo '<p class="help-block">'.form_error('skill').'</p>';
    ?>
 .......
```

Comment: Should `echo set_value('skill');` be `get_value()` ?

Comment: Try turning on display_errors/error_reporting (or check the php error log) to see what error php gives you.

Comment: You dont need to check if the message is empty as it will only show if one exists.  either use echo validation_errors() or echo form_error('field') No conditionals needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<p class="help-block">'.form_error('skill')).'</p>';
```

you have an extra close paren after form_error.

Comment: Have you tried running `php -l <myfile>` on the command line? That should show you an actual error message....

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<p class="help-block">'.form_error('skill')).'</p>';
```

There's an extra closing bracket at the end of the function call - that might be the issue?